# Rails PG Database Mishap, Can I Drop DB and reload with different schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I mistakenly used a nested resources model_id column as a STRING instead of an INTEGER. Can I wipe my DB, change the data type in db/schema from string to integer, reload the schema and the DB and get moving? I'm trying to change the manufacturer_id field in LINES model to integer, because I'm stupid. I don't need any of the data in the DB, if I lose it, it's no big deal.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140316023038) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "lines", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "manufacturer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "lines", ["manufacturer_id"], name: "index_lines_on_manufacturer_id", using: :btree

  create_table "manufacturers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "manufacturers", ["user_id"], name: "index_manufacturers_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "fax"
    t.string   "inside_sales_office"
    t.string   "inside_sales_cell"
    t.string   "inside_sales_email"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new migration:

```
rails g migration change_manufacturer_id_in_lines
```

Then update the migration file as follows:

```
class ChangeManufacturerIdInLines < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   change_column :lines, :manufacturer_id, :integer
   add_index :lines, :manufacturer_id  
  end

  def down
   remove_index :lines, column: :manufacturer_id 
   change_column :lines, :manufacturer_id, :string
  end
end
```

Delete the records from `lines` table. (As you suggested, deleting existing data is not a problem).

```
Line.delete_all
```

or

```
Line.destroy_all
```

After this run `rake db:migrate`